# Mac OS X with Windows-like path bar for Finder?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, finder

I'm new to OS X and I like the operating system. The only problem is, I'd like to have a Windows-like path bar in Finder, where I could, for example, enter "/user/Desktop/" to go to the Desktop. I know there's a way to show what path you're in at the bottom of the window, but I want more of a textbox area to type in whatever I want.

Are there any add-ons or tweaks in OS X I can use for this? I checked out a program called PathFinder, but I rather not use that one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying and pasting the path within Finder](http://superuser.com/questions/18930/copying-and-pasting-the-path-within-finder)

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to pop down the "Go to Folder..." sheet in any Finder window, allowing you to type in a path.

Be warned that tab-completion in that field uses a piss-poor algorithm. Also, "/" doesn't get you "/".

Comment: However `~` does get you your home folder, and `/Volumes` gets you your volumes list.